# Python: Reggular Expressions filtering for Self Learning program

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, artificial-intelligence

I am making a program that has a small way of self learning, but now I want to get "information" from the output like:

```
>>>#ff0000 is the hexcode for the color red
```

I want to filter with `reggular expressions` that the user filled this sentence `is the hexcode for the color`, and that I retrieve the name of the color and the hexcode. I have put a small code below how I want to works:

```
#main.py

strInput = raw_input("Please give a fact:")

if "{0} is the hexcode for the color {1}" in strInput:
    #  {0} is the name of the color
    #  {1} is the hexcode of the color
    print "You give me an color"

if "{0} is an vehicle" in strInput:
    #  {0} is an vehicle
    print "You give me an vehicle"
```

Is this possible with `reggular expressions`, and what is the best way to do it with `reggular expressions`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read about [regular expressions in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in the standard library documentation.  Here, I'm using named groups to store the matched value into a dictionary structure with a key that you choose.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '#ff0000 is the hexcode for the color red'
>>> m = re.match(r'(?P<hexcode>.+) is the hexcode for the color (?P<color>.+)', s)
>>> m.groupdict()
{'color': 'red', 'hexcode': '#ff0000'}
```

Note that if there's no match using your regular expression, the `m` object here will be `None`.